# Error desconocido, Problema al compilar relacionado con JDK

Tags: java

Estoy terminando un proyecto en **Intellij** para la universidad, ese proyecto lo deje en *stand by* mientras seguí con otros compromisos.

Sin embargo hace unas semanas instale un framework y al no correr correctamente des-instale y volví a instalar **java** para que corriera, sin tener éxito.

Ahora al retomar el proyecto ya no corre y siempre marca error.

[image]
Al intentar abrir el proyecto en eclipse aparece esto:

[image: al intentar abrir el proyecto en eclipse aparece esto]

---

Ya revise variables de entorno y todo bien, volví a instalar java y JDK. Sin embargo sigue apareciendo el error, lo peor de todo es que no solo es con este proyecto que tengo que realizar, sino que ya es con todos los programas.

Adjunto screens del error. si necesitan mas información por favor escríbanme, no se que hacer.

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te marca al compilar?

Comment: el que se encuentra en la parte de abajo, adjunte 2 imagenes, una del codigo y otra de la consola cuando marca el error

Comment: el que se encuentra en la parte de abajo, adjunte 2 imagenes, este es el error que sale: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpR7n.jpg

Comment: Tendrías que configurar de nuevo tu Java en Intellij

Comment: no creo que tenga que ver con intellij, ya que intentanto abrir otro IDE como eclipse, me salio algo muy similar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fPqx.jpg

Comment: Por eso, te dice que no encuentra la maquina virtual de java en esa dirección.

Comment: aqui tienes una pregunta respuesta bastante consultada quizas es lo que busca esta en ingles -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030434/eclipse-no-java-jre-jdk-no-virtual-machine  pero puesto que comenta que es un proyecto quizas tenga prisa y este de los nervios, por otro lado para este caso quizas no se tan relevante, pero cuando tenga que poner fragmentos de codigo siempre ponerlos en formato de texto en la medida de lo posible, pero mirelo por el lado bueno si es en todos sus proyectos, sabe que el error no es de su codigo, y es muy posible que en algun momento lo solucione. Saludos

Comment: P.D: en la pregunta en ingles en la parte de la derecha de de interface tiene pregunta bajo Link que posiblemente esten relacionadas con ese error puede mirar por ahi si la anterior no soluciona su problema. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel mejor publicar una respuesta en español ;)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza si ya, si la OP no hubiera dicho su situacion, es muy posible que no de hubiese comentado nada, es por eso que le deje un link que pienso que podria ayudarla, por otro lado si usara eclipse y mas aun con Windows quizas podria intentar dejar una respuesta como quisiera, pero no es el caso, es por eso entre otras que le deje un link, y quizas este mismo ayude a alguien a testearlo y dejar una respuesta en español. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel lo que digas, pero sigue siendo mejor una respuesta en español.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza obviamente mejor una respuesta buena en español, pero como dicen por algunos lugares: *a falta de pan buenas son tortas* o eso pensaria yo de estar en el lugar de la OP solo quise intentar ayudar. Saludos

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Por que eclipse me marca este error?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79287/por-que-eclipse-me-marca-este-error)

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que agregar la carpeta bin correcta asociada al binario de Java que deseas ejecutar, teoricamente al instalar de nuevo el JDK esta ruta debería agregarse, pero por lo que veo en tu comentario la ruta parece erronea.

Una forma facil de verificar si java esta funcionando bien es abrir Powershell y escribir `javac`, si la consola te dice que el comando no se ha encontrado es que tienes problemas de path.

Porfavor actualiza tu pregunta con la ruta en la que instalaste el JDK para explicarte como configurar la variable de entorno PATH.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

dale click derecho a mi pc -> propiedades-> variables de entorno donde dice variables del sistema buscas la que diga path ahi le das en editar pones ;

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin**  tienes que verificar que esa sea la ruta correcta  muy probablemente tendras que reiniciar tu pc