# ¿Por que eclipse me marca este error?

Tags: eclipse, java

He buscado muchas veces este error:

> "A Java runtime environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must
>   be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual Machine was
>   Found after searching the following location: location"

Varios dicen que es por que utilizo un `jdk de 32 bits` en lugar de uno de `64 bits`, sin embargo me sigue desplegando el mismo mensaje.

Comment: Pues básicamente te dice que no encuentra la maquina virtual de java, puede que en la configuración de tu Eclipse la ruta que tiene no es la correcta.

Answer (score 1):

Ejecuta java y javac en la consola, ambos comandos deben de volver unos códigos, si alguno no lo hace, debes de configurar las variables de entorno JAVA_HOME a donde esta instalado java, Path al JAVA_HOME/bin, y si existe la variable CLASSPATH agregarle `;.;`

Y con eso debe funcionar, si vas a desarrollar apunta todo a un jdk y no a un jre, ya que el jre no trae todo el compilador, solo sirve para ejecutar aplicaciones ya hechas no para desarrollo. Para desarrollo usa el jdk.

Reinicia la consola y prueba de nuevo los comandos y ya deben funcionar ambos.

Si el error persiste agrega:
`-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.8\bin\javaw.exe`

al eclipse.ini, la ruta depende de tu instalacion.